# How to inject component programatically at specified place of <ng-template>?

Tags: angular, ng-template

How to instantiate a component programatically and insert it at specified place within template?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-do71xk

```
import {Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, TemplateRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, Type} from "@angular/core";

export interface PaneOptions {
  component: Type<any>;
  params?: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manager',
  template: `
    <ng-template #paneContainer></ng-template> <!-- probably redundant -->

    <!-- window template -->
    <ng-template #paneTemplate>
      <div style="background: red">
        <h3>Window header</h3>
        <ng-template #paneBody></ng-template> <!-- or another ng-template -->
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class ManagerComponent {
  @ViewChild('paneContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) paneContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('paneTemplate', {read: ViewContainerRef}) paneTemplateRef: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('paneTemplate', {read: TemplateRef}) paneTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  addPane(options: PaneOptions) {

    // create embedded view of pane template
    const embeddedView = this.paneContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.paneTemplate);

    // resolve component and insert it into pane container
    // instead, we need to clone #paneTemplate and insert component within <ng-content>
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(options.component);
    const component = this.paneTemplateRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

    Object.assign(component.instance, options.params);
  }
}
```

And this is different approach when I try to instantiate component inside inner ng-template.

```
import {Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, TemplateRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, Type} from "@angular/core";

export interface PaneOptions {
  component: Type<any>;
  params?: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manager',
  template: `
    <ng-template #paneContainer></ng-template>

    <!-- pane template -->
    <ng-template #paneTemplate>
      <div style="background: red">
        <h3>Below within red area should be the inner component</h3>
        <ng-template #inner></ng-template>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class ManagerComponent {
  @ViewChild('paneContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) paneContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('inner', {read: ViewContainerRef}) innerTemplateRef: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('paneTemplate', {read: TemplateRef}) paneTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  addPane(options: PaneOptions) {

    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(options.component);
    const component = this.innerTemplateRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    Object.assign(component.instance, options.params);

    // create embedded view of pane template
    const embeddedView = this.paneContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.paneTemplate);
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzx7vz

However, I get error:

> Error: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined

I'm writing a window manager using Angular. Is it possible to inject component into specified place of window's template and then insert the window into main container? I want to keep reference to each window to be able to remove it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make three main changes for this.

1. Need to write a host directive which will host your dynamic
   component as explained here - https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader
2. Catch hold of your host directive using

   `@ViewChild(HostDirective, {static: false}) hostDirective;`
3. Delay your component loading to next change detection - using `setTimeout`

You can refer this stackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbjr75